# openssl ca -revoke causes `Can't open ./demoCA/cacert.pem`

Tags: tls, certificates, openssl, certificate-revocation

I'm learning for the first time the concept of revoking certificates.   I created a certificate with openssl then I tried to revoke it.  But my revoke command causes an error.

Here's what I did

```
# generate key
openssl genrsa -out root.key 2048
# generate certificate
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -nodes -key root.key -subj "/C=CA/ST=ON/O=HelloWorld/CN=root.example.com" -days 3650 -out root.crt
# revoke root.crt
openssl ca -revoke root.crt -keyfile root.key
```

But this gives the error:

```
Using configuration from /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
Can't open ./demoCA/cacert.pem for reading, No such file or directory
140443365868864:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('./demoCA/cacert.pem','r')
140443365868864:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
unable to load certificate
```

I'm not clear what `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf` is relevent or mentioned given that I used the `-keyfile` to explicitly specify the `root.key` file.  I've tried omitting `-keyfile root.key` but still get similar error.

Can anyone explain to me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial dupe [How do I revoke the certificate and generate a CRL?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/169605/how-do-i-revoke-the-certificate-and-generate-a-crl) and compare to [Revoke a certificate without index.txt](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43557/revoke-a-certificate-without-index-txt)

The `openssl ca` command does three related but different things to manage certificates:

1. by default, issue one or more cert(s) from CSR(s) using a preexisting, configured CA key and certificate, a simple serial counter, and containing extensions from the configuration and/or copied from the CSR(s), *and* record the issued cert(s) in a very simple database (a tab-separated text file whose name is configurable but conventionally, i.e. in the upstream config, is ./demoCA/index.txt)
2. with `-revoke`, modify the database to mark as revoked a cert previously issued *by this CA* (and recorded in the database)
3. with `-gencrl`, generate a CRL containing the cert(s) currently marked as revoked in the database

All of these are described on the man page which should exist on your system if not (native) Windows, or [on the web](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-ca.html). In addition the `openssl ocsp` command has a 'server' aka 'responder' mode in which it uses the same database (i.e. index.txt file) to handle OCSP requests for this (one) CA.

And you didn't do any of them. You can't use `openssl ca` to do step 2 without having done step 1 first, and you can't usefully do step 3 without steps 1 and 2 first.

Moreover entries in the index.txt file are identified only by serial number and must all be for one CA, or more exactly one Issuer name, which steps 1 *and* 3 automatically supply from the Subject name of the CA cert you use for the issuance and generation respectively.

In contrast, `openssl req [-new|newkey] -x509` creates a *self-signed* cert, not one issued by *any* CA. **A self-signed cert cannot be revoked**, because there is no issuing CA to be the authority for the revocation. A suitable self-signed cert *can* be a root CA cert, as the names in your command suggest is intended, and the `x509_extensions` used in the conventional (upstream) config are tailored for that case, because a root CA by definition has no superior -- and cannot be revoked.

Note this differs from PGP, where in the original design a key can be signed by *multiple* other 'ordinary' keys (not a special CA), but can only be revoked by itself. However post-Hagrid the web-of-trust no longer works very well; using it is either manual and quite tedious, or dangerous.